# iOS Unit Test target can't include host app's files that reference frameworks

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcode7

Using XCode 7. Have an app that uses a 3rd party framework (old style xxx.framework, not post-iOS8 dynamic frameworks). Host app includes the framework files using the syntax

```
<MyExternalFrameworkNameHere/SomeFile.h>
```

and builds fine. I can #include using (quote-style) files from the host app that do **not** use any external frameworks in the unit test target .m file and the test target builds just fine. However when the test target references a file from the host app that itself includes a 3rd party framework the test target fails to build saying it can't find the header. Example:

Host app header named SomeHeader.h:

```
#include <UIKit/UIKit.h> // OK
#include <MyExternalFrameworkNameHere/SomeFile.h> // doesn't like this in test target
```

XCTest target AppTests.m:

```
#include "SomeHeader.h" //fails saying it cant find MyExternalFrameworkNameHere/SomeFile.h
```

If the test target directly includes the offending external framework file like this:

```
#include <SomeFile.h>
```

It works, but that doesn't help as I need to test the host app code that uses the framework, **not** the framework itself. What am I doing wrong here? I've tried adding the external framework to the test target's Link with binaries... but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Framework Search Paths had a typo and was not set to the same value for the unit test target as the host app target